# My input statements are being ignored on my program

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring, scanf, fgets

I'm a beginner in Objective C, so no high complicated words please.
I'm doing a program that removes certain characters (vowels, consonants, punct etc.) but when I tried for the user to input their own statement, the compiler just ignore my `fgets`(statement), and it ignores my while loop condition the second time. The problem is on line 81-87(allows the user to input what characters they want removed) and line 98(the while loop input statement. Again I'm not a pro, just know some basics. Sorry for the improper formatting. I don't know stackoverflow that well

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#define max 100


//characters is the character that the function is going to check for
NSCharacterSet *isChar(NSString * characters)
{
     NSCharacterSet * theChar=[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:characters];
    return theChar;
}
NSString *removeChar(NSString * myInput , NSString * characters)
{

    NSString * name;
    name=[NSMutableString stringWithString:myInput];
    name = [[name componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: isChar(characters)] componentsJoinedByString: @""];



        return name;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        char myString[max];
        char tempWord[max];
        NSInteger length =0;
        NSInteger otherlength=0;
        NSString * NewString;
        NSString * characters;
        NSString * myInput;        
        int k = 0;
        char l=('y');

        NSLog(@"Enter a String");
        fgets(myString, max, stdin);
        length=strlen(myString);
        myString [length - 1] = 0;


        myInput= [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:myString];
        while (l=='y')
        {

        NSLog(@"What would you like to do?");
        NSLog(@"1:Remove Vowels");
        NSLog(@"2:Remove Punctuation");
        NSLog(@"3:Remove Constanants");
        NSLog(@"4:Remove Digits");
        NSLog(@"5:Remove whatever you want");
        scanf("%d",&k);
        if (k==1)
        {
            characters=@"aAeEiIoOuU";
        }
        if (k==2)
        {
            characters=@"!@#$%^&*()+_-|}]{[';:/?.>,<";
        }
        if(k==3)
           {
               characters=@"qQwWrRtTyYpPsSdDfFgGhHjJlLzZxXcCvVbBnNmM";
           }
        if (k==4)
        {
           characters= @"1234567890";
        }
        if (k==5)
        {//My problem starts here
                NSLog(@"Enter a String");
                fgets(tempWord, max, stdin);
                otherlength=strlen(tempWord);
                tempWord [length - 1] = 0;


                characters= [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:tempWord];

        }



        NSLog(@"Your orignal string is: %@ ", myInput);
        NewString=removeChar(myInput,characters) ;
        NSLog(@"Your new string is: %@", NewString);

        NSLog(@"Do you want to continue?");
         //The scanf works the first time but when it goes thru the loop the second time it 
         //it gets ignored
        scanf("%c",&l);
        }
        NSLog(@"Take Care :)");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `scanf("%d",&k)` reads only the number, but not the *newline character*
that you typed in the terminal. Therefore the next `fgets()` reads just this newline and nothing else.

One possible fix is to use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`, because this always reads an
entire line including the newline terminator, so:

```
//scanf("%d",&k);
fgets(tempWord, sizeof(tempWord), stdin);
k = atoi(tempWord);
```

and

```
//scanf("%c",&l);
fgets(tempWord, sizeof(tempWord), stdin);
l = tempWord[0];
```

(Note that `fgets()` returns `NULL` if nothing was read at all, so you should check
for that condition in your code.)

Comment: I'm confused about how you explained it... Again in new to programming... But i tried it and it worked! So thank you!